# Installing a SignalR dll on dev IIS7.5 machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I developed a SignalR app and, by default, when I want to debug it, it creates a 'site' that points to http://localhost:16969/
The App is actually an ASP.NET web application.

And this is great for debuging, but now I want to do some load testing, (still on my machine), so I would like to 'install' the ASP.NET application.

Can anyone give me a step by step tutorial on how to install my ASP.NET web application using my IIS7.5, (the one on my dev machine, not the actual server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I get it correctly you want to switch from IIS Express to the full IIS.

You need to:

- install IIS (through the "Turn Windows features on or off" dialog)
- go to IIS manager
- right-click "Default web site" and click "Add application"
- you should be done now

There is an alternative way (easier for some):

- go to the Visual Studio
- right-click your web project and go to Properties
- go to "Web" tab and change "Servers" to "Local IIS"
- it'll create an application for you within the "Default web site" in the IIS

Always try to keep the IIS bindings and VS's Web tab in sync so that when you hit "Debug" it'll attach to the app in the IIS.

Comment: Thanks, I already have IIS installed on my machine, (IIS7.5).
I can then add the application, (or the dll), but when I navigate to the site, it does not work, (or at least, it does not work as it does with VS).
I will try the debugger option to see if that works.

Comment: The second "easier" solution was enough for me.
Aslo, the values created by visual studio make it somewhat easy to move the site somewhere else if I want to.